# SOLVED: "t" in useTranslation() hook of react-i18next does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, i18next, react-i18next

**PS: This problem was solved. Someone answered here but it seemed the comment was deleted. For anyone interested, after removing the `{}` in the `translation` prop of `resources`, it worked. I decided to leave this question here in case you may encounter the same problem as I did.**

I am currently working on a React project with Material UI. I am implementing react i18n in my project. I followed the init file of react-18next official document to configure i18n. And the language translation won't work. Have been searching for related questions here but still couldn't find a solution. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot.

My code for i18n.js:

```
import React from "react";
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";
import enLocales from './enUS.json'
import znHKLocales from './zhHK.json'
import zhCNLocales from './zhCN.json'
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';

i18n
    .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
    .use(LanguageDetector)
    .init({
        resources: {
            enUS: { translation: { enLocales } },
            zhHK: { translation: { znHKLocales } },
            zhCN: { translation: { zhCNLocales } },
        },
        lng: localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng') || 'enUS', 
        fallbackLng: "enUS",
        saveMissing: false,
        returnObjects: true,
        debug: false,
        interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false 
        },
    });

export default i18n;
```

My code for the locales.js (I put all of the related languages function here):

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageContext from '../context/LanguageContext'
import { enUS, zhHK, zhCN } from '@mui/material/locale';


const useLangLocales = () => {
    const context = useContext(LanguageContext);
    const { i18n, t } = useTranslation();
    const currentLangStorage = localStorage.getItem('i18nextLng');

    const LANGS = [
        {
            label: t('English'),
            value: 'enUS',
            systemValue: enUS,
        },
        {
            label: t('Chinese (Hong Kong)'),
            value: 'zhHK',
            systemValue: zhHK,
        },
        {
            label: t('Chinese (Simplified)'),
            value: 'zhCN',
            systemValue: zhCN,
        },
    ];

    const handleChangeLang = (newLang) => {
        console.log('newlang ', newLang)
        i18n.changeLanguage(newLang.value);
        context.setLangMode(newLang.systemValue);
    }

    return {
        onChangeLang: handleChangeLang,
        allLang: LANGS,
        t, //I export the t here, it is imported from the useTranslation() hook above
        enUS,
    }
}

export default useLangLocales;
```

My code for changing language in react componenets:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Container, Box, Typography, Button } from '@mui/material';
import useLangLocales from '../hooks/useLangLocales';

const Home = () => {
    const { t } = useLangLocales();

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="md">
            <Typography>{t("Home")}</Typography>
        </Container>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

My code for index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './locales/i18n'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

My package.json:

```
    "i18next": "^22.4.14",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.0.1",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^2.2.0",
```

The language is changed successfully when I console log my handleChangeLang() function. The translation won't work, i.e., the `t("Home")` value won't change.

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox to replicate this?

Comment: @TusharShahi Hi, thanks for the reply. This problem was actually solved. Someone answered here before but it seemed he deleted the comment.